# Alamofire doesn't execute the URL

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, alamofire

I have a server running in node, I tried using postman and it works just fine, but when I execute it from IOS client, it doesn't execute the URL, I checked my server it doesn't even called the API

Node server

```
router.post('/api/accounts/login', (req, res, next) => {
   var user = new User():
   user.name = req.body.name;
   user.pass = req.body.password;
   user.save((err) => {
     res.json("Success");
   });
});
```

Alamofire

```
let mainURL = "https://examplelogin.com"
let facebookLogin = "\(mainURL)/api/accounts/login"

func loginButtonTapped(_ name: String, _ pass: String) {

        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "name": name as AnyObject,
            "password": pass as AnyObject
        ]

        Alamofire.request(facebookLogin, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)

                    // Do something


                }
        }

}
```

To be more specific, I hosted my node server on Heroku, I use namecheap to get the full domain name, but for somehow my ios client doesn't execute the API, do i need to add anything on the Info.plist?

Comment: Alamofire doesn't even execute the API

Comment: @sinusGob you set "Content-Type" and check?

Comment: Do you get any warnings in the debug pane?

Comment: try this and see error : else if let ERROR = response.result.error
            {
                print(ERROR.localizedDescription)
            }

Comment: Sorry my last answer is mistake. Are you sure this address is yours? https://examplelogin.com/api/accounts/login

Comment: This is what I got `Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004`

Comment: I got this error when I run your code, `Could not connect to the server.` @Dix

Comment: Should I clean my app or something?

Comment: @sinusGob
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
 <true/>
</dict> add this code in info.plist and try.

Comment: Maybe the response only contains error, print `response.result.error` instead

Comment: @Dix this definitely solved the problem. put your answer so that I could accept, thanks mate :)

Comment: @sinusGob puted answer, happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

1.add this code for show error.

```
else if let ERROR = response.result.error { 
   print(ERROR.localizedDescription)
}
```

2.Add this code in info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict> 
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/> 
</dict>
```

Comment: `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict> 
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/> 
</dict> `  this code definetely saved me!

Comment: @sinusGob happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code ...

func loginButtonTapped(_ name: String, _ pass: String) {

    let parameters = [
                "name": name,
                "password": pass
            ]
            Alamofire.request(facebookLogin, method: .post, parameters: parameters as [String : AnyObject], encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let json = JSON(value)

                        // Do something

                    }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but i have solved by doing this : -

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:dict (the dictionary you want to pass which contains parameters), options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

```
    let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: jsonString, encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        switch(response.result)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: No. JSON string is for humans. JSON data is for computers. You don't *need* to convert the data to a string representation. If your server demands a JSON string then fix your server. But this is not the solution to give for this question. // And anyway you're doing it wrong. Why would you initialize an NSString then force cast it to a String?! You should directly make a String. All in all, this whole code is useless and unnecessary.